# Spring Security throwing an error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a spring boot application with a REST service and I implemented Spring Security in it. In my project, I extend OncePerRequestFilter and override its method doFilterInternal(). I also used jackson dataformat library in my project. When I call an API it throws following an exception.

```
16:45:47,203 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createContentReference(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/ContentReference;
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1082)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
16:45:47,204 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
16:45:47,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
16:45:47,206 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.security.UUIDAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(UUIDAuthenticationFilter.java:55)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
16:45:47,207 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
16:45:47,208 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.security.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:36)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,209 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
16:45:47,210 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
16:45:47,211 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
16:45:47,212 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:45:47,214 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
16:45:47,215 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
16:45:47,216 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
16:45:47,218 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
16:45:47,218 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createContentReference(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/ContentReference;
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:497)
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:30)
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:425)
16:45:47,219 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
16:45:47,220 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    ... 119 more
```

I have already followed some of the old threads on a similar issue. But those are not directly related to the versions I am using. This is how my related pom.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <name>my-project</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.12.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.net.httpserver/http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>20070405</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitbucket.cowwoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>diff-match-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my code

```
@Component
public class UUIDAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UUIDAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private final String HEADER = "Authorization";

    private final ISystemUserRepository systemUserRepository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOGGER.info("Inside doFilterInternal of UUIDAuthenticationFilter");
        
        try {
            if (checkUUIDToken(request, response)) {
                SystemUser systemUser = validateToken(request);
                if (systemUser != null) {
                    setUpSpringAuthentication(systemUser);
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error in UUIDAuthenticationFilter");
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            PrintWriter responseWriter = response.getWriter();
            if (e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().contains(":") && e.getMessage().split(":") != null
                    && e.getMessage().split(":")[1] != null) {
                response.setContentLength(e.getMessage().split(":")[1].length());
                response.setStatus(500);
                responseWriter.write(e.getMessage().split(":")[1]);
            } else {
                response.setContentLength(e.getMessage().length());
                response.setStatus(500);
                responseWriter.write(e.getMessage());
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    private SystemUser validateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String UUIDToken = request.getHeader(HEADER);
        LOGGER.debug("UUIDToken is " + UUIDToken);
        try {
            SystemUser systemUser = systemUserRepository.findByApiKey(UUIDToken);
            if (systemUser != null && systemUser.getRole() != null) {
                return systemUser;
            }
            systemUser = systemUserRepository.findByLoginTokensContains(UUIDToken);

            if (systemUser != null && systemUser.getRole() != null) {
                return systemUser;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error in validateToken in UUIDAuthenticationFilter");
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Authentication method in Spring flow
     * 
     * @param
     */
    private void setUpSpringAuthentication(SystemUser systemUser) {
        try {
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.stream(systemUser.getRole().split(","))
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            UUIDAuthenticationToken auth = new UUIDAuthenticationToken(authorities, systemUser.getPassword(),
                    systemUser.getEmail(), systemUser.getClient().getClientRef());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkUUIDToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) {
        String authenticationHeader = request.getHeader(HEADER);

        if (authenticationHeader != null && !authenticationHeader.isEmpty())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public UUIDAuthenticationFilter(ISystemUserRepository systemUserRepository) {
        this.systemUserRepository = systemUserRepository;
    }
```

chain.doFilter(request, response);
this line of code causes an issue
Here is my mvn dependecy tree

```
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:8.12.11:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.net.httpserver:http:jar:20070405:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO]       +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]       \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
```

Comment: This would indicate you have incompatible versions of Jackson dependencies on your classpath (e.g. different versions of jackson-dataformat-xml and jackson-core). `JsonFactory._createContentReference` was added in Jackson 2.13 (`JsonFactory` is the parent of `XmlFactory`), so it looks like you have a jackson-core 2.12 or older and jackson-dataformat-xml 2.13. Make sure your dependencies are consistent.

Comment: please post your full pom.xml

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, I added my full pom.xml file

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, I'm using the latest `jackson-dataformat-xml` and `jackson-core` version which is 2.13.1 for both.

Comment: The error suggests otherwise. I would recommend to carefully look at the output of `mvn dependency:tree`, and if you deploy to an application server, make sure it doesn't have its own version of Jackson on the classpath.

Comment: `com.vladmihalcea.com.vladmihalcea:2.11.1` seems to have a compile dependency on `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` 2.11 so i believe it pulls in an old version of jackson. If you provide the output of the command `mvn dependency:tree` as written above we'll know. Several of your dependencies are outdated and have documented vulnerabilities i suggest you update all your dependencies.

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, how to find dependency vulnerabilities can you please suggest.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I added my mvn dependency tree with the question can you please check.

Comment: i checked and it is incomplete, you seem to have copy pasted just a bit from the full output. Please update with the full output

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare, thank you for your response I uploaded my file to the cloud you check the full dependency tree. here is the link:- [link](https://easyupload.io/yu4o28)

Comment: I will not download a random file from someone random on the internet. Update your question or use something like pastebin

Comment: @Toerktumlare I understand I uploaded code in the Pastebin here is the Link:- [Dependency Tree](https://pastebin.com/VYTPETWF)

Please see if you can find the cause of the error. If not maybe it's coming from the Wildfly classpath as we have Wildfly wildfly-26.0.1.Final with the code installed in it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Thank you for your response I uploaded code in the Pastebin here is the Link:- [Dependency Tree](https://pastebin.com/VYTPETWF)

Please see if you can find the cause of the error. If not maybe it's coming from the Wildfly classpath as we have Wildfly wildfly-26.0.1.Final with the code installed in it.